# LaTeX compilation problem

Tags: errors, pdftex

I am getting this while trying to compile literally my first document

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./t1.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./t1.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \latex

?
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The command is either  `\LaTeX` or `\LaTeXe`. You should show us the document `t1.tex` actually.

Comment: Please add a MWE so we can try it out for ourselves. From the error message it seems you use a command that has not been defined -- that is `\latex`. Please keep in mind that commands are case sensitive and you probably wanted to use `\LaTeX`.

Comment: Having the command `\LaTeX` etc that early in the document looks strange. It should occur after `\begin{document}`, not before (and spelled correctly, of course)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It's on line 6, apparently, and is after `\begin{document}` (based on `(./t1.aux)`).

Comment: @JosephWright: True, I didn't notice the `.aux` file: Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Both `TeX` and `LaTeX` are case-sensitive, i.e. it matters whether a command is written with uppercase or lower case letters.

Most likely, the command `\LaTeX` was intended, but was spelled as `\latex` which is wrong (unless somebody defines this command)

So out of the 32 possible variants of `\latex`, `\Latex`, `\lATeX` etc. only `\LaTeX` is correct ;-)

Please note that there is a special `\LaTeXe` command to output the `LaTeX2e` variant.

The example below shows also the difference between the font size command `\huge` and `\Huge`, i.e. where lowercase and uppercase forms provide significantly different output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\huge
\LaTeX\ is very nice, 
\LaTeXe\ is very nice too, but
\LaTeX3 is yet to come! 

\Huge
\LaTeX\ is very nice, 
\LaTeXe\ is very nice too, but
\LaTeX3 is yet to come! 

\end{document}
```

[image]